# jQuery - toggle (show)

Tags: jquery

The default of toogle is hide after click.
How can I show div after click my button?

Below is my code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#openJokeTxt").click(function(){
        $(".uploadJoke").toggle(800);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle? because it looks good

Answer (score 1):

> The default of toogle is hide after click

Wrong, [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) hides element if the value of it's 'display' property is not 'none', and shows it if it's value is 'none'.
So all you need is a css rule:

```
<style>
.uploadJoke{
    display:none;
}
</style>
```